# Why does this Stack Overflow URL link to Super User?

Tags: support, migrated-questions, redirection

Everything seemed to be answered on meta and I felt that I had done my duty. Assuming that if I simply deleted the "meta" in front of the current URL, I would be able to go right to Stack Overflow – sure, it might send me to the 404 page, but whatever, I can click on the big `stackoverflow` button and it would take me right to interesting questions. Apparently not.

- I started at [Don't show visual indicator that a vote succeeded until server response is received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/).
- I deleted the `meta` and then I arrived at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686/
- This redirects me to [OpenOffice 2.4.1 in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/106817/).

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug. The post that was previously at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686/ was migrated to Super User, which is why you're being redirected. In all other cases you wouldn't be.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if you look at the original question it has a different ID, 55518 instead of 55686. I also can't find any information in Data Explorer (except for two votes) on post 55686.

Comment: Not only does it have a different ID, I generally am not forced to do a redirect if I somehow get to a closed question.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Redirects are added after a migrated questions has been closed for a month, IIRC.

Comment: Closed, no; migrated, yes.

Comment: @jtbandes:  You can see confirm that the question on SO was #55686 here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/55686/edit.

Comment: @jtbandes: We're both wrong, [see this meta discussion for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73593/do-closed-migrated-questions-always-redirect-now). Apparently links to the closed post *from* SO add a query parameter so you aren't redirected, but if you enter the URL like cwallenpoole did, you will be redirected.

Comment: Yes, but the question remains why the ID changed...

Comment: @jtbandes: I'm confused: Where are you seeing the different ID?

Comment: @Jeremy: If you visit the question on Super User, and click the "migrated from stackoverflow.com" link, you end up at question 55518 on SO.

Comment: @jtbandes: It took a minute, but I've got it: 55686 was the id of an answer to question 55518. You can confirm this by looking at the title link on the /edit page I posted above.

Comment: Aha! Good call. And of course that makes sense; IDs are unique across questions *and* answers (they're both `Posts` in the database).

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to go from a meta site to its corresponding main site is to click the `main` link in the header. If you pick an essentially arbitrary question id, you might pick one that has (as in this case) been emigrated.

Answer (score 1):

The ID can be of question or **answer**. If you go to `/questions/[ID of answer]` you will be automatically redirected to `/questions/[ID of question]` that's probably the reason for different numbers.

55686 is most likely ID number of answer on SO, and its corresponding question has been migrated to superuser.com getting whole new ID there.